# How to configure JPA multiple persistence unit in SOA

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am using SOA and have multiple persistence.xml (each component dependent on DB). I am using Spring + JPA. Code sample as below:

In Core:

```
Code:
public abstract class GenericJpaDAOImpl<T extends BaseEntity> implements GenericJpaDAO<T> {
    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
}
```

In Component SSO:

```
Code:
public class UserDAOImpl extends GenericJpaDAOImpl<User> implements UserDAO {
    /* Any method specific to UserLogin */
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sso", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.entityManager;
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml

Code:

```
<persistence-unit name="sso" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Application XML

```
Code:
    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ssoDataSource" />
    <property  name="persistenceUnitName" value="sso"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ssoDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="<URL>"/>
        <property name="user" value="<USER>"/>
        <property name="password" value="<PASSWORD>"/>
    </bean>
```

Similarlly Component: Billing (as Above)

I got similar thread on http://forum.springsource.org/showth...sistence-units but this does work for expected behaviour. In my case If application context xml for Billing gets loaded first DAO operations works file for this component but SSO component does not work. Please suggest and let me know if more detail is required.

Comment: please rephrase your exact problem, and explain how the behaviour is not expected

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple data sources, you can configure your DAOs to target a specific Session using the `@Qualifier` annotation, as follows:

```
@Autowired
public MyDAOImpl(@Qualifier("someSessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```